# Apache Rewrite Permalinks on non-WordPress site

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite, url, permalinks

I've inherited a legacy PHP site running on Apache with a custom CMS. The URL structure is currently:
https://example.com/topic.php?id=100&Title=Blog+Post+Topic

Is there an easy(-ish) way to automatically map that URL to a more friendly URL using an Apache rewrite so that the URL is like:
https://example.com/blog-post-topic/

It reminds me of how WordPress permalinks map its /?p=100 style URLs to /blog-post-topic/

Any and all help is certainly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Most probably you will have to create a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out.